# JavaScript endWith()

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble getting the following to work

```
if(str.endsWith('+')
{
   alert("ends in plus sign")
}
```

How do I escape the plus sign? I've tried /\ +/ but it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess you should clarify your question. 1) You are missing a bracket in the if condition, 2) String.endsWith nor String.endWith are not standard javascript functions.

Comment: See my comment on your accepted answer; there's an IE gotcha you'll want to be aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `endsWith` method in JavaScript, so instead use:

```
if (str.substr(-1) === "+") {
  alert("ends in plus sign")
}
```

Comment: Negative indexes (`str.substr(-1)`) don't work on JScript (IE). To be reliable cross-browser, you need `str.substring(str.length - desiredSub.length)`.

Comment: You can, however, use `slice`, which works with negative indexes even in IE.

Answer (score 3):

The Javascript String type doesn't have an `endsWith` function, but you can give it one if you like:

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
    (function() {
        String.prototype.endsWith = String_endsWith;
        function String_endsWith(sub) {
            return this.length >= sub.length && this.substring(this.length - sub.length) == sub;
        }
    })();
}
```

Or if you don't mind unnamed functions:

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(sub) {
        return this.length >= sub.length && this.substring(this.length - sub.length) == sub;
    };
}
```

Either way, you could then do:

```
if ("foo".endsWith("oo")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yea Sorry I should have wrote above, I had added an endsWith prototype. Thank you

Comment: This version is marginally faster: `var i= this.length-sub.length; return i>=0 && this.indexOf(sub, i)===i`. Prototype and a few others use this approach.

Comment: @bobince: Good point, although I'd have to say I can't imagine a real-world difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.endswith= function(c){
    if(!c) return this.charAt(this.length - 1);
    else{
        if(typeof c== "string") c= RegExp(c + "$");
        return c.test(this);
    }
}
```

var s='Tell me more:', s2='Tell me about part 2:';

s.endsWith() // returns ':';

s.endsWIth(':') // returns true, last character is ':';

s2.endsWIth(/\d:?/) // returns true. string ends with a digit and a (possible) colon

Comment: `'spoon!'.endswith('.')` - whoops. Careful making regexps from string. Also, `endswith('')` won't do what you might expect due to the overloading condition.

Answer (score -1):

Use RegExp:

```
    a = "csadda+"
    if (a.match(/.*\+$/)) {
        alert("Ends");
    }
```